# An interesting infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^i}
$$

I thought this series would be pretty easy to crack with a power series, but it has proved intransigent. Is there a closed form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: In general, whenever you have a term in the summand like $n^{-n}$, it is generally difficult to find a closed-form for the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is called [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). There's no closed form for it, but the following equalities holds:
$$
\int _{0}^{1}x^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^i}
$$
And
$$
\int _{0}^{1}x^{x}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^i}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to derive a differential equation - initially I mistakenly thought y'=1-y would satisfy it, but obviously not. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Ah, Not at all :)